# Security tower wants Snowflake audit records in SIEM

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our Security group is asking for us to have Snowflake audit records ingested into our on prem SIEM by the end of the quarter.  I've found the information_schema.login_history records but I'm struggling to find anything else that the SIEM might want (privilege usage, etc).  Any tips on relevant views or functions would be appreciated.

Comment: Along with login history we also export query history to see all grants etc being given and also to see the type of data being queried and possibly being exported

Comment: You may be interested also with [ACCESS_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html)

Answer (score 0):

some tables can be used to understand query & login attempts by Snowflake users along with various dimensions. For details take a look at:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/login_history.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

Comment: Thank you for the links.  We think along the same lines.  The first link is one I used the second is one I looked at but you've made me look further to see if we can leverage it.  Thank you.  Other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the SNOWFLAKE ACCOUNT_USAGE SCHEMA QUERIES that may come handy.

Access_History ,Query_History will help to find out who and How the Snowflake DB is been accessed and Query History will show the queries executed ,Role ,Warehouse,start time ,end time etc.

Also try to login to Snowsight get the full lineage of a specific Role.

--TO FIND THE ACTIVE USERS IN THE ACCOUNT--
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DISPLAY_NAME from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."USERS"
WHERE DELETED_ON IS NULL GROUP BY FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DISPLAY_NAME
ORDER BY FIRST_NAME DESC;

--TO FIND THE ACTIVE USERS AND ROLES IN THE ACCOUNT--
SELECT ROLE,GRANTEE_NAME,GRANTED_BY FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_USERS"
WHERE DELETED_ON IS NULL
GROUP BY ROLE,GRANTEE_NAME,GRANTED_BY
ORDER BY GRANTEE_NAME DESC;

--TO FIND THE ACTIVE GRANTS ON ROLES TO OBJECTS--
SELECT PRIVILEGE,TABLE_CATALOG,GRANTEE_NAME,GRANTED_BY FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."GRANTS_TO_ROLES"
WHERE DELETED_ON IS NULL
GROUP BY PRIVILEGE,TABLE_CATALOG,GRANTEE_NAME,GRANTED_BY
ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG;